# passing two variables on onclick event in combo box

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
         <select name="Country">
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="A">A</option>
         <option value="B">B</option>
         </select>

           <select name="Gender" onchange=func(this.value, country)>
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="M">m</option>
          <option value="F">F</option>
          </select>
```

i have 2 dropdown boxes named gender and country. 
First i select the value from Country
Then i select the value from gender
On onclick event i want to pass the values of gender and country. I am not not able to pass
the value of gender.Is there any way by which i can pass the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. You gave the element the name `Country`, not `country`. It also has a `value` property. You also need to quote the attribute value whenever it has spaces.

```
<select name="Gender" onchange="func(this.value, Country.value)">
```

Note that this has **nothing** to do with JSP. What you've there is just HTML and JavaScript. JSP is merely a HTML/JavaScript code generator.